# Smart PayPal Buttons in React, disable the button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, paypal, paypal-buttons

I have this implementation of the [PayPal smart buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) in React:

```
function PayPalButtonComponent(props: PayPalButtonProps) {
  const [show, set_show] = useState(false);
  const [error, set_error] = useState<string>();

  const create_order = (_: any, actions: any) => {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency: props.currency || "EUR",
            value: props.total
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  };
  const handle_approve = (_: any, actions: any) => {
    return actions.order.capture().then((details: any) => {
      if (props.onSuccess) props.onSuccess(details);
    });
  };
  const handle_cancel = () => {
    if (props.onCancel) props.onCancel();
  };
  const handle_error = () => {
    if (props.onError) props.onError();
  };
  const render_button = () => {
    const Button = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
    return (
      <Button
        style={{
          layout: "horizontal",
          size: "responsive",
          shape: "rect",
          color: "gold",
          tagline: false
        }}
        funding={{
          allowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CARD, paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL],
          disallowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT]
        }}
        createOrder={create_order}
        onApprove={handle_approve}
        onError={handle_error}
        onCancel={handle_cancel}
      />
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isScriptLoaded) {
      if (props.isScriptLoadSucceed) set_show(true);
      else set_error("Unable to load the paypalscript");
    }
  }, [props.isScriptLoaded, props.isScriptLoadSucceed]);

  if (error) return <p>{error}</p>;
  if (!show) return <FakeButton />;

  return render_button();
}
```

I have struggled to implement these buttons in react since there is no documentation, I have found and copied some code from [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-paypal-payment) and trying to guess other stuff. But I can't understand how to disable the button.

In [this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/validation/) they state that one can call the disable() method on the actions object but can't figure out how I can accomplish that with my configuration.

Have you ever try something similar? Do you know any documentation one can follow?

**edit**

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set the button in a disable state during the payment. I know there is the paypal overlay, but when the transaction completes I change the app route and since it happen when onSuccess is called, due to the apparent async nature of actions.order.capture() this can't happen instantaneously, and so there is a moment when one can click again on the paypal button. If i can disable the button i have solve the problem.

The onInit implementation allows you to disable/enable the button before clicking on it, useful for some sort of validation before the checkout (like terms checked) but doesn't apply to my case. I have also tried to call actions.disable() in `create_order` but that breaks the button.

Comment: The documentation you linked to shows an `onInit` function that sets up a listener that calls `actions.disable()` based on events that happen. This seems straightforward enough. Have you tried implementing that? If not, why not? What would you like to do instead? Your question does not specify.

Answer (score 0):

Have same situation here and the onInit example from documentation is not that straight forward as some think... You would need to create hidden imput and assign somsort of variable to it when payment made in order to achieve buttons to be disabled after payment. To bad no one solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

For React, I would use the official PayPal NPM ([@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://github.com/paypal/react-paypal-js)) package. They have some good documentation on how to use it... in your case just use the  component and you can set if its disabled or not as an attribute.

Checkout their code example:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider,
    PayPalButtons,
    usePayPalScriptReducer
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

// This values are the props in the UI
const amount = "2";
const currency = "USD";
const style = {"layout":"vertical"};

// Custom component to wrap the PayPalButtons and handle currency changes
const ButtonWrapper = ({ currency, showSpinner }) => {
    // usePayPalScriptReducer can be use only inside children of PayPalScriptProviders
    // This is the main reason to wrap the PayPalButtons in a new component
    const [{ options, isPending }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: "resetOptions",
            value: {
                ...options,
                currency: currency,
            },
        });
    }, [currency, showSpinner]);


    return (<>
            { (showSpinner && isPending) && <div className="spinner" /> }
            <PayPalButtons
                style={style}
                disabled={false}
                forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
                fundingSource={undefined}
                createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                    return actions.order
                        .create({
                            purchase_units: [
                                {
                                    amount: {
                                        currency_code: currency,
                                        value: amount,
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        })
                        .then((orderId) => {
                            // Your code here after create the order
                            return orderId;
                        });
                }}
                onApprove={function (data, actions) {
                    return actions.order.capture().then(function () {
                        // Your code here after capture the order
                    });
                }}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "750px", minHeight: "200px" }}>
            <PayPalScriptProvider
                options={{
                    "client-id": "test",
                    components: "buttons",
                    currency: "USD"
                }}
            >
                <ButtonWrapper
                    currency={currency}
                    showSpinner={false}
                />
            </PayPalScriptProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```